# Rectangle drawing in itemize

Tags: lists, itemize

Can you help me to get the rectangle at the end ?:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
  \item Set a rank threshold K 
  \item Compute \% relevant in top K
  \item Ignore documents ranked lower than K
  \item Ex:
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not TikZ, even if you tagged it as such:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\ClrSquare[1]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
  \item Set a rank threshold K 
  \item Compute \% relevant in top K
  \item Ignore documents ranked lower than K
  \item Ex: \ClrSquare{green}\ClrSquare{red}\ClrSquare{green}\ClrSquare{red}\ClrSquare{green}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need several such things, it can be done a bit easier with a loop from e.g. `pgffor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgffor}
\newcommand\ClrSquare[1]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{7pt}{7pt}}}
\newcommand\ClrSquares[1]{\foreach\x in{#1}{\ClrSquare{\x}}}
\begin{document}  
\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
  \item Set a rank threshold K 
  \item Compute \% relevant in top K
  \item Ignore documents ranked lower than K
  \item Ex: \ClrSquares{green,red,green,red,green}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the second example having two macros is not needed. One could also make the size an optional argument.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Delan Sure, no problem. (I didn't really *explain* anything though ...)